# Java Envers import

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, hibernate-envers

I have to import history data from an old application to the new one.

The new app is using Spring, with Envers for data history.

Data is migrated using Spring Batch, using the same repositories than the final application, with same data configuration.

What is the recommanded way to add revisions (the old history) to the audited entities ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did the old application use Envers or some other auditing mechanism?

Comment: The old application has no automatic auditing. For "audited" entities, there is an "<entity>_histo" table, containing the old value, change date, user, entity id.

The simplest way is to do a raw import from source tables (entity and its histo table) to destination tables (newentity, its "aud" table, and "revision" table).

But I don't know the side effects for Envers.

Comment: Do you intend to use the `DefaultAuditStrategy` or `ValidityAuditStrategy` ?

Comment: I think that it is DefaultAuditStrategy. I don't see anything related to auditing strategy in the application. This part has been done by another dev.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to preface this answer that this is based on use of `DefaultAuditStrategy`.  An entirely different approach would be required using any other strategy.

It seems you want to store user information for each revision.  To do that with Envers, you're going to need a custom `REVINFO` table.  You can do this by providing a custom `@Entity` that is also annotated with `@RevisionEntity` and Envers will pick that up automatically.  In order to give Envers the current user, you will need to supply a `RevisionListener` implementation too.  You can see the documentation on how to create such a implementation.

Then you can either elect to use the hibernate-tools project or the Hibernate schema tool activated by setting one of the *hibernate.hbm2ddl_auto* configuration properties to create the database schema.  Once you have this schema, you're free to transport it however you wish from development to your other environments.

In order to then populate the information, you'll want to take an generate a revision number for each change.  You'll store the revision number, the timestamp, and user who created the revision in the `REVINFO` table.  Additionally, all entities modified during that revision will be stored in their respective audit tables, using the entity's primary key and `REV` value from the `REVINFO` table as the audit table's primary key.

Now, you  mentioned that your old table stores the `old value`.

Envers actually records the *current state* as it relates to the revision rather than the *prior state*.  This means you'll need to probably massage your incoming data to determine the *current* rather than *old* state information somehow.

Now if you're planning to use various other configuration options of Envers such as *withModifiedFlags*, let me know and I can update the answer wrt to those as needed.

Hopefully this gets you started.